# How to update row data then insert the latest data on mysql

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have 'Home' table to save all data from importing csv file to phpMyAdmin. At first, the table not containing any data and i import a csv file that contain field (home_id, name and count). The table have additional field 'status' default to 1 and home_id is set as unique key. Now the table 'Home' have data.

home_id | name | count | status

H1 | Apartment  | 3  |  1

H2 | Condominium | 6 | 1

H3 | Cottage | 4 | 1

Next, i import same csv file but with updated value for 'count'. By using `INSERT INTO....DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, i manage to update row that have same home_id and set 'status' as 0.

home_id | name | count | status

H1 | Apartment  | 8  |  0

H2 | Condominium | 9 | 0

H3 | Cottage | 4 | 1

But i want to save data before and after updated for example as below table.

home_id | name | count | status

H1 | Apartment  | 3  |  1

H2 | Condominium | 6 | 1

H1 | Apartment  | 8  |  0

H2 | Condominium | 9 | 0

H3 | Cottage | 4 | 1

I realize that i cannot set 'home_id' as unique key because it will not allowed to save same 'home_id'. Is there any way i can do? I still cannot figure out on this.

Additional: Before i `INSERT INTO...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to 'Home' table. I `LOAD DATA INFILE` to a temp table, 'Home_Temp' consist field (home_id, name, and count). Then i `INSERT INTO` to 'Home' table consist field (home_id, name, count and status). The 'Home_Temp' table is created when user click button for import file and drop after a insert process to 'Home' table.

Comment: After you've loaded the new data into `Home_Temp`, update it based on the latest values for each `home_id` in `Home`. Then write those updated values to `Home`

Comment: I'm sorry, i cannot understand on update based on latest values for home_id. @Nick

Comment: you would need an auto-incrementing `id` column or similar so then the "latest" value for a given `home_id` would be the one with the highest `id` value.

Comment: It is mean i have to do the update latest value on `Home_Temp`?. Because `Home_Temp` table is created when user click button for import file and drop after a insert process to `Home` table. @Nick

Comment: Something like `LOAD DATA INFILE INTO TABLE Home_Temp; UPDATE Home_Temp SET status = 0, count = count + (SELECT count FROM Home WHERE home.home_id = Home_Temp.id AND id  = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Home h2 WHERE h2.home_id = Home.home_id)); INSERT INTO Home SELECT * FROM Home_Temp;`

Comment: Incase there is another field `area`, `price` and `owner` is same as field `count` (it mean, it can be update). I have to do update latest field for each field? `count`, `area`, `price`, `owner`. @Nick

Comment: I don't know your data well enough to answer that.

Comment: We know what isn't unique , but why not tell us what is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from @Nick, i find idea to solve this problem. I add field 'id' that auto increment. This query will find the highest home_id based on id and will update the status to '0'.

```
$sql = "UPDATE Home h1 INNER JOIN (
        SELECT home_id, MAX(id) AS max_id 
        FROM Home GROUP BY home_id) h2 
        ON h1.home_id = h2.home_id 
        AND h1.id = h2.max_id 
        SET h1.status = '0'";
```